# Problem bounding name to a class in Django

Tags: python, django, class, django-views

I've got a view function that has to decide which form to use depending on some conditions. The two forms look like that:

```
class OpenExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Extra

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OpenExtraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['opening_challenge'].label = "lame translation"

    def clean_opening_challenge(self):
        challenge = self.cleaned_data['opening_challenge']
        if challenge is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Укажите шаг, открывающий данную доп. возможность')
        return challenge

class HiddenExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Extra
        exclude = ('opening_challenge')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HiddenExtraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The view code goes like that:

```
@login_required
def manage_extra(request, extra_id=None, hidden=False):
    if not_admin(request.user):
        raise Http404
    if extra_id is None:
        # Adding a new extra
        extra = Extra()
        if hidden:
            FormClass = HiddenExtraForm
        else:
            FormClass = OpenExtraForm
    else:
        # Editing an extra
        extra = get_object_or_404(Extra, pk=extra_id)
        if extra.is_hidden():
            FromClass = HiddenExtraForm
        else:
            FormClass = OpenExtraForm

    if request.POST:
        form = FormClass(request.POST, instance=extra)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view_extra, args=[extra.id]))
    else:
        form = FormClass(instance=extra)
    return render_to_response('form.html', { 'form' : form,
                                              }, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

**The problem is** somehow if `extra.is_hidden()` returns True, the statement `FromClass = HiddenExtraForm` doesn't work. I mean, in all other conditions that are used in the code it works fine: the correct Form classes are intantiated and it all works. But if `extra.is_hidden()`, the debugger shows that the condition is passed and it goes to the next line and does nothing! As a result I get a UnboundLocalVar error which says FormClass hasn't been asssigned at all.

Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decide between `FromClass` and `FormClass`.  You use `FormClass` everywhere except:

```
    if extra.is_hidden():
        FromClass = HiddenExtraForm
```

Comment: oh my God what a stupid mistake! I am an idiot. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: No, you're just going blind.  After a certain amount of work on code, everything starts to look correct, no matter how wrong it really is.  That's why it's good to take breaks and get others to look at your code.